# Is it possible to control mplayer from another program easily?

Tags: php, scripting, mplayer, openbsd

I'm setting up a computer running OpenBSD that I wish to play all the music I will ever want. I want it to basically set in a corner and do it's thing. The problem with that is that I want to control it from wherever I am. I can do that (though not extremely easily) with ssh from my computer. I think it'd be really cool to control(as in, choose songs, skip, pause, volume control, etc) it from a simple web page so I could access it from my phone, as well as my computer.

So, I'd prefer to use mplayer for this. Is there any way of controlling mplayer from say a PHP script or something similar?

Comment: If all else fails, use `exec`.

Comment: @Rafe, well, the problem I'm seeing is controlling things like volume from within my script. Things where you can't just simply kill the process and restart it

Comment: You can use `mplayer -slave` and set up a fifo node, which in turn could be feeded from a socket handler (inetd script) which could be called remotely by php.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/tech/slave.txt

You can start up mplayer in command receival mode. Create a named pipe first:

```
mkfifo /tmp/mplayercontrol
mplayer -slave -input file=/tmp/mplayercontrol
```

Which in turn can be controlled via PHP easily:

```
file_put_contents("/tmp/mplayercontrol", "pause");
```

If you run mplayer and PHP on the same server, that should already do it.

Comment: Oooh, neat and simple :) Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

mplayer has a remote control (slave) interface.

http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/tech/slave.txt